# Extracting the longest subSequence from a list. Can't figure out the TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I have a task where I need to find the longest sub sequence in a list. I have made this function in python

```
def subSequence(sequence):

    newSequence = [0]
    longest = [0]

    for x in range(0,len(sequence)):
        print("x is " +str(x)+"\n")
        if sequence[x] == sequence[0]:
            newSequence.append(sequence[x])

        elif sequence[x] > sequence[x-1]:
            print("sequence[x] = " +str(sequence[x]))
            print("sequence[x-1] = " +str(sequence[x-1]))
            newSequence.append(sequence[x])

        else:
            if longest <= newSequence:
                del longest[:]
                longest.append(newSequence[:])
                print("longest = "+str(longest))
                del newSequence[:]
                newSequence.append(sequence[x])
            else:
                del newSequence[:]

    return newSequence

mySequence = [1,2,3,2,5,6,7,2]
print(subSequence(mySequence))
```

It all worked untill I added the last 2 to the mySequence variable now I'm getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Calum/Desktop/subSequence.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(subSequence(mySequence))
  File "D:/Calum/Desktop/subSequence.py", line 15, in subSequence
    if longest <= newSequence:
TypeError: unorderable types: list() <= int()
```

I'm not too sure how just adding the 2 is making the type error happen

The output should be `2,5,6,7` as it's the longest sequence of numbers in ascending order

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
          longest.append(newSequence[:])
```

seems to be appending a list to `longest`, make that:

```
          longest.extend(newSequence[:])
```